# StAX - Is it possible to convert an XML node to HashMap (OR POJO class with a hashmap)

Tags: java, xml, streaming

I am using Streaming XML API for parsing a huge XML file (size~10 M, #objects ~ 100K)..

Is it possible to convert an XML node like -

```
<A>
<C>b </C>
<D>c </D>
<E>d </E>
<F>e </F>
<G>f </G>
</A>
```

to a Java HashMap? Or a POJO class with HashMap as the only member.. such that this hashmap contains all name-value pairs..

EDIT - I need to use Streaming API for parsing XML. I want to do something like this -

```
//reach a start element
while(reader.isStartElement());
//until u reach end element
'XMLNode' value = getNodeValue(reader);
//convert XMLNode to POJO

//getNodeValue looks like this
while(reader.isEndElement()) {
    //read file
    //collect all characters until end element 
}
//produce XMLNode
```

Comment: I bet you can do it with the Jackson XmlMapper.  https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml  You'd need a POJO A with a map in it.

Comment: It can be done with jackson, but only if you know the root element name.  Do you know the root element name in advance?

Comment: yep i know the root elem.. but I am using streaming XML API as my XML file is very big.. plz see the edit..

Comment: ah, I'd have to look it up.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this with Jackson if you know the root element name.  You need a POJO like this:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "A")
public static class POJO{

    private Map<String,String> map = new TreeMap<String,String>();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, String> get() {
        return map;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void set(String name, String value) {
        map.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

then read like this:

```
    ObjectMapper xmlmapper = new XmlMapper();        
    POJO p2 = xmlmapper.readValue(xml,POJO.class);
```

I just posted the full code on my blog: http://demeranville.com/deserialising-json-or-xml-to-a-map-using-java/ (it works for JSON too)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something has changed, but using Jackson 2.4.4 I can easily read an XML doc to a Map without creating a POJO/knowing the root element name:

```
ObjectMapper xmlmapper = new XmlMapper();        
Map setup = xmlmapper.readValue(setupFile, Map.class);
```